# Angular 9 change the attribute value of an element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to change the attribute value of an element but the new value is not set in the element

Any Best standard practise of Angular through which we can achieve the below problem

```
 <div name="hai"  (click)=test($event)  #ckechName>
```

in Ts file

```
test(event){

let exmpl=event.currentTarget
exmpl.getAttribute('name')  //I am able to retrieve this valu as hai

exmp.setAttribute('name','hello')  //This is value is not setting as hello in the dom..It is still showing hai
```

}

Comment: add `[attr.name]="greeting"` to your element. In your ts add the property `public greeting = 'hai' ` and in your test function do `this.greeting = 'hello' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this solution

```
  @ViewChild('ckechName', {static: true}) myCkechName:ElementRef;
```

And in your function `test` you can do like

```
this.myCkechName.nativeElement.value = 'hello';
```

You dont need to pass `$event` in test function

Hope useful